# Four types of sources for Halochos

Tags: halacha-theory

In our Kolel I have found a printed page with the following content and I would like to know if it's just somebody's private summary or has a source:

> Four types of sources for Halochos (from the Talmud):
>
> **1. Mind:** Halachos that are accepted entirely by the tradition (like הלכה למשה מסיני) and that are not backed by writings. For example, The knot of Teffilin or its color.
>
> **2. Speech:** Halochos that the Sages derived from the writings by the 13 Middos of or else. For example Kid 41: "א"ר יהושע בן קרחה מנין ששלוחו של אדם כמותו שנאמר ושחטו אותו וכו'"
>
> **3. Middos:** Halachos and regulations that are derived by the Sages from personal views and estimations. For example, זה נהנה וזה לא חסר, or גוד או אגוד, husband's obligations toward his wife and other monetary Halochos.
>
> **4. Action:** The Sages' (*or Tanach heroes', AB*) behavior that became de-facto Halocho without any other Limud or discussion. For example: "רב הונא בריה דרב יהושע לא מסגי ארבע אמות בגילוי הראש אמר שכינה למעלה מראשי"

Comment: See derech tvunot from ramchal

Comment: http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=31529&st=&pgnum=23&hilite=

Comment: @kouty Sorry I couldn't see a similarity. He talks about the nature and the proof of the laws.